# Distorted picture with VLC

Tags: drivers, video, vlc, acer

I use the newest Ubuntu on an Acer Veriton 6800. When I play DVDs with VLC, the pictures are distorted.

Can anyone please tell me how to correct this?

[image: Distorted picture]

Comment: Do you see any useful error messages if you start VLC from the command line? Or when using any other video player that produces this distortion?

Comment: Best starting point is to alter your video out device in the vlc Video settings. Some experimentation will be in order...

Comment: Is it the same in other video players, e. g. Totem?

Answer (score 0):

From Tools drop down menu select preferences, then video and select open GL - if I am looking at this correctly, yours is set on ASCII art.